# How to read hocon file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hocon

I have a project where configuration info for the app are in hocon files. I want to write integration tests with information from those files. How can I get into those files and then map them to objects? In my program I do this with `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration` object and I add to a project as singletons, but how to get access to this in project with tests?

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly? Surely you can write a `IConfigurationSource` and `IConfigurationProvider` for HOCON files (or someone has already done that perhaps). Edit: yep, they have: https://github.com/Muraad/Hocon

Comment: The example shows how to create a hocon, but how to get info from hocon from existing file?

Comment: By using `IConfiguration` ? I don't understand your question.

Comment: And that example doesn't show how to create a HOCON file. It shows you how to register the configuration source that's contained within that GitHub repository so that you can use HOCON files in your application.

Comment: I would like to give a path to my existing hocon file in order to use it

Comment: Well, that specific code either takes the HOCON file as a string or a stream: [source code](https://github.com/Muraad/Hocon/blob/master/Nulands.Framework.Configuration.Hocon/HoconConfigurationExtension.cs). There's nothing to stop you from modifying this to read from a file, of course.

Comment: and that's the problem :) Besides, I cannot find this package to install in order to use

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a package. I think you're just expected to include that code in your project. Either way, the point is that you can use this person's implementation of `IConfigurationSource` and `IConfigurationProvider`, find another one, or DIY it. And it's not really a problem if the only options are the config as text or as a stream, since you could just pass `File.OpenRead(myHoconFile)` to the method that takes a stream.

Comment: it os a little overkill to copy all this code to my project https://github.com/Muraad/Hocon/blob/master/Nulands.Framework.Configuration.Hocon/HoconConfigurationExtension.cs and it uses some small, not well know package I don't wanto to be linked with. But thanks for help

Comment: It's overkill? Do you currently have a way of reading HOCON files? What exactly is the problem you're solving here, because I'm still not clear on it.

Comment: And I wasn't saying you had to. I was just saying it was one of _many many_ options. Please read what I say carefully.

Comment: I wanto to write tests, that uses the hocon files I already have in my project. The tests are in seperate project, and I dont know how to get into these hocon files.
My problem is that I don't see `many and many` options of solving this problem, that's why I wrote here

Comment: The missing link here is: how are you currently adding HOCON configuration files to your existing project? And why can't you do the same in your tests?

Comment: I don't want to copy the same hocon files into the project with tests and keep updating them in two places

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve here?